# How do I use std::formatter directly?

Tags: c++, fmt, stdformat

Let's say I want to format a single object directly using `std::formatter`, bypassing `std::format`. How do I do that?

According to [*Formatter*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Formatter), I need to call `.format(value, format_ctx)`, where `format_ctx` is a `std::format_context` or `std::basic_format_context<...>`. But how do I construct this context?

The standard doesn't seem to provide a way to construct one. And looking at [libstdc++ sources](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6d16e460240fe547cb7d9648f91494126213c835/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/format#L3557), the member variables of `basic_format_context` are all private, there's no non-default constructor, and no way to set them without being a `friend`.

Does this mean that `std::formatter` is impossible to use manually by design?

---

**Why am I doing this?**

I want to format a value using the "debug format" (`"{?:}"`) if it's supported, falling back to the regular `"{}"`.

The way to check for support seems to be `requires(std::formatter<T> f){f.set_debug_format();}`, and I figured that if I'm already interacting with the formatter directly, I might as well use only the formatter itself.

Comment: This is indeed strange considering that `fmt` does have the public constructors: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/649fe0fc8b9366375eab67639cab404617c527cd/include/fmt/core.h#L1712

Comment: @WeijunZhou is it possible that implementation is incomplete? Afaik there is no full c++20 one yet

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The standard itself doesn't document public constructors here, it seems.

Comment: Dose this C++23 concept help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formattable

Comment: @Red.Wave I don't see how it helps.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat last paragraph.

Comment: @Red.Wave What about it? The unspecified default iterator type means I can't really use `std::format_context`, alright, but `std::basic_format_context` lets you specify a custom iterator, so I thought I could do that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat for the iterator you need to sparately check `std::output_iterator<iter, const CharT&>`. It is unlikely that a type specializes for a specific iterator, but very likely that it only specializes for `char`(default). Do you want to specialize on iterator?

Comment: Finally you call `it=std::format_to(it,fmt,...);`

Comment: @Red.Wave *"Do you want to specialize on iterator?"* No, I'm asking how to call `std::formatter` directly. I don't care what iterator it uses internally as long as it works, I'd probably use it with `std::back_inserter`. The only reason why I'm talking about custom iterators is because the default iterator type used by `std::format_context` is unspecified, so I can't use it directly, so I need a different type if I want to construct `basic_format_context` manually.

Comment: "Does this mean that `std::formatter` is impossible to use manually by design?" It is abundantly clear that `std::formatter` is impossible to use manually (portably at least). The standard just doesn't give you any way to construct one. The only remaining question is whether it is by design. I don't know for sure because I don't have relevant design documents, but from the looks of it, it seems so.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI `std::formatter` itself is required to be defaut-constructible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correction, "any way to construct one" => "any way to construct arguments to `formatter ::format`". And it is required to be defaut-constructible because the library should be able to default-construct it. The programmer is not supposed to.

Comment: `std::format_context` doesn't need any magical iterator type. The iterator comes from first argument to `std::format_to` which is an instance of `basic_string::iterator` identified by `basic_string_view` instance taken from `basic_format_string::get` which in turn is identical to the `basic_string_view` that captures `fmt`. All you need to check about iterator is concept `std::output_iterator<iter, const CharT&>`.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm asking how to use `std::formatter` *without* `std::format` (and without any similar functions, such as `std::format_to`).

Comment: I don't understand why you need to touch the context. Context is obviously supposed to be reserved for library internals, not for user to tamper with. It os created from the upperhand range which maybe created from a stream. You need to create a costume range class and let `format_to` create the context. If you want to create a temporary context for a range type, then good luck with that: https://youtu.be/EQELdyecZlU?feature=shared

Comment: @Red.Wave practically speaking, current fmt group is least usable\flexible thing that exsts in the realm of format output. It's fastest to use, slowest to runtime one. Funny thing..  so hated `printfs\scanfs` still stay the most flexible one and  libraries with similar capabilities behave either in similar way or use regex flavors. fmt was clearly designed by someone coming from front-end development.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `printf` has always been an will always be a big nono in C++ . C variadic functions are just relics from the past. `scanf` is even worse. `{fmt}` is created by a well rounded C++ expert. I might not agree with the design, but it's by far the best we've got. strong type-checking, compact syntax and readability are it's advantages; the only major problem is lack of foresight for genericness and scale. `printf` can't even provide minimum extensibility. If I were to design fmt, I'd start with tuple as the primary formatable type.  I am no fan of SWIFT; neither Taylor, nor Apple's.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie *"slowest to runtime"* Do you have any source for that? [Libfmt's readme](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) has some benchmarks, and they look quite good.

Comment: @Red.Wave The problem arises where you need a constant stack and linear predicatable time footprint. None of C++ versions have either  (and boost and QT's  .arg are the worst in stack case, fmt can compete is  libc IF it uses same format line foor every output  on x64.. but looses badly to libc and libc++ on some ARMs and VLIW). henyour stack is only  0.5-1.5 Mb for a process and your time deviation should be, let say, +/- 3 ms, that's these are a no-no.  `printf` by definition got linear stack footprint and matching time with two forks, by design.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah, though they crafted benchmark against ostream version . Thereis even a way make printf slower than C++ if you use particular pattern. Also really dependant on arch. My target arch is a 96bit VLIW CPU, stand-alone {fmt} is the slowest, and we don't have a C++20 capable compiler yet (newest compiler is C++14)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I am sure you're mistakeing `vformat` with `format`. `format` prcesses the fmt string at compile-time; So combined with `fputs` or `fwrite`, it should outperform `printf`. Because `printf` must interpret fmt at runtime.

Comment: @Red.Wave most of our use cases ARE run-time. among other things it's not permitted to spread output through compilation units. One can slightly cheat it by making some kind of intermediate dispatching.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie if you need to craft the fmt string at runtime, you have both design and readability problem. Even in C, it's very rare that the fmt string is not a core constant expression.

Comment: @Red.Wave If you're localizing the messages, all the strings will be created at runtime.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and if someone says "you can separate formatted code from localized", they will be wrong(I met some Canadian dev like that once) they will be wrong because even numbers are displayed differently depending on locale or context.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie what do you mean by localizing messeges? I fail to see why the fmt string(first argument to `format`) should not be a core constant expression.

Comment: I guess we have different understanding about what the term **fmt string** means.

Comment: @Red.Wave Means that content of string depends on current locale setting of software or OS or even  program's settigs or current context (write into particular width?). And sometimes even more dynamically than that. In `{ arg-id (optional) : format-spec }`  the `format-spec` wouldnt be a core constant

Comment: For further clarification, I am referring to the first parameter sent function `format` or `printf`. Your seem to be confusing it with return value from `format`.

Comment: @Red.Wave Say you're writing a game, and you have `fmt::format("You have {} HP", player_health)` displayed somewhere. `player_health` is only known at runtime, so the format string needs to be localized, not the return value. You can't localize `"You have "` and `" HP"` separately, because that's 1. not convenient, and 2. not feasible if there's >1 `{}`, since they might need to be reordered in different locales.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat On technicality you can use `"{} {} {}", YouHaveString, HPValue, HpString`. Only that's unworkable because with different language  order on number of arguments will change and that is compile-time thing. `{}` in other context may contain width specifier because we trying to format all numbers based on.. e.g. Excel table comun's width. So even that becomes flexible.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Aha! So you basically need a diversity of fmt strings to choose from. Indeed those fmt string need to be built from core constant expressions. The choice(e.g. index) is however made at runtime. All the information about `std::wformat_string` is provided at compile-time and can be saved as part of type information. I can show you how to avoid `vformat` and use `format` instead. But that requires another discussion thread.

Comment: Not always they can be a part of code, because localization is done for already complete (and copiled) program by certified specialist. Not by devs, though in real life it includes a lot of back and forth because of some issues with localization support in code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use case you're describing, where you never actually call `std::(v)format(_to)` and just use the formatter directly, isn't supported. You should just call `std::format` with the format string that you want to use, i.e., `{}` or `{:?}`.

And even if you could bypass `std::format`, you would just be creating work for yourself. You'd have to call `std::formatter<T>::parse` *and* `std::formatter<T>:format` manually (since the former sets up state that is used by the latter). And you'd have to manually set up the contents of the `std::basic_format_parse_context` and `std::basic_format_context` objects, assuming that they supported that in the first place.

On the other hand, a formatter can invoke another formatter, by passing down the `std::basic_format_parse_context` and later the `std::basic_format_context` that were passed to it by the library. That's basically how you'd implement a range formatter (if it weren't for the fact that the standard already provides one).

Comment: `creating work for yourself`  that's an argument for front-end developer, where "less code is better". We're still in realm of system software design. But yeah, `fmt` is designed as a front-end tool and there is no way around it except "do not use it" otherwise.